# Remove a column in R when there's too many NA in it

Tags: r, missing-data

I'd like to write some code that would check if columns have NA values in it and how much so that if it is superior to a certain value, the column will be removed from another tab.

I have got this for now :

```
tab2=tab

for(i in 1:145){

  x=sum(is.na(tab[,i]))
  print(x)

  if(x>10550/2) {

  tab2 <- tab[,-i]

  }
  x=0
}
```

My dataset is composed of 145 columns and i do know that at least half of them should be removed, yet this code only removes one column, as if the loop execute itself once. I have tried several thnigs but non worked. Any ideas ?

Comment: Look at this line: `tab2 <- tab[,-i]`  a bit more closely and you should be able to see why this is happening. Should be `tab2 <- tab2[,-i]`. Voting to close as a typo. (The loop did execute 145 times but you are only seeing the result of the last iteration.

Comment: ... may be a typo... but the answers are useful :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a more useful approach than a loop would be to use `colSums(is.na(.))` to get the number of NA per column, then apply your logical condition.  We can then use the output of that logical operation to do a column subset to get the desired output.

```
tab[, colSums(is.na(tab)) <= 10500/2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
data_used <- data.frame(month = c(1:5), 
                 var0 = c(1,2,5,6,8),
                 Var1 = c(rep(NA,3),1,1),
                 Var2 = c(rep(NA,3),3,2),
                 Var3 = c(rep(NA,2),5,3,2))
new_data <- data_used %>% 
    select_if(.predicate=funs(sum(is.na(.))<=2))
```

Comment: As of dplyr 0.8.0 this would be the current implementation of this solution: ```new_data <- data_used %>% select_if(~ sum(is.na(.)) <= 2)```